# How do I assign a value in a column from one row to another row that has an NA, based on a condition in another column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with duplicate IDs and I want to keep only one ID row for each person based on the condition of the smallest "time" value.

The issue though is that some of the rows with the smallest time value do not have a test score which I need.  Ultimately I want to only have one row for each ID, and this one row should be the smallest time value, and if there is an NA for the test score in that row, then I would like to fill in the NA with a test score from the next smallest time value row. So for example in the table, ID A's smallest time value row doesnt have a test score, so the score assigned should be 5 because that score has the next smallest time value. And for ID B, the smallest time value row has a test score so no work is needed there.

I have used this code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(IDs) %>% 
  filter(time == min(time)
```

to keep only one row  and I am exploring with this code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(IDs) %>% 
  ifelse(is.na(test score), )
```

but Im confused on how I would approach this issue.

[table output link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlx3G.png)

Comment: We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(df)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: You can use the common "last observation carried forward" method to fill in the `NA` values before filtering (make sure your data is sorted by time first). With `library(tidyr)`, should be something like `df |> arrange(IDs, time) |> group_by(IDs) |> fill(score) |>  filter(time == min(time)`.